# Some summary stat for each column in DF in R

Tags: r

Let's say that a dataframe contains four columns

```
set.seed(123)
x1 <- runif(10,0,1)
x2 <- runif(10,0,1)
x3 <- runif(10,0,1)
x4 <- runif(10,0,1)
DF <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

For each column, I want to calculate the number of observations that are less than or equal to 0.5. Here is my code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
a <- vector()
pvect1 <- vector()

for (j in 1:ncol(DF))
{
  for (i in 1:nrow(DF))
  {

    if (DF[i,j] <= 0.5)
      a[i]=1
    else
      a[i]=0 

    pvect1[j] <- cumsum(a[i])    

  }
}
```

Finally, I want to create a new dataframe (let's call it DF2) that contains two column (C1 and C2) where C1 is the column name in DF (x1, x2, x3, and x4), and C2 is the number of observations that are less than or equal to 0.5 for each column in DF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do `colSums` on a logical `matrix` to find the number of TRUE elements in each column

```
v1 <- colSums(DF <= 0.5)
```

For creating a `data.frame`,

```
DF2 <- data.frame(C1 = names(v1), C2 = v1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

---

If we really need to use `for` loops

```
a <- vector() #it is better to pre-allocate the size
pvect1 <- vector() #same comment as above

for (j in 1:ncol(DF)) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) {

    if (DF[i,j] <= 0.5) {
        a[i]=1
        } else {
            a[i]=0
        }

     }
   pvect1[j] <-  sum(a)   
 }
```

Checking with the vectorized solution

```
identical(as.vector(v1), pvect1)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @user9292 Glad to help you.  It is just that you didn't think about `colSums`.  It happens to me many times..

Comment: On a side note, can you please if possible point out why my code doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @user9292 If you are usinga  `for` loop, still you can avoid the nested loop with `pvect1 <- vector();
for(j in seq_along(DF)){

 pvect1[j] <- sum(DF[,j] <= 0.5)
}`

Comment: @user9292  I updated with a modification of your `for` loop

Comment: Thanks. This helps me to better understand how R works.